# loop through json inside json

Tags: jquery, json

I have a json collection, and inside each item I have other collection:

I'm walking in the first json item:

```
$.each(data, function (index, element) {
    var tmp = $('#itemBusca').html();
    $('#buscas').append(_.template(tmp, element));
});

[{
    "Codigo": "692547",
    "Afiliacao": "RS",
    "Nome": "155 HOTEL",
    "Provincia": "BRSAO",
    "NomeProvincia": "SAO PAULO",
    "Categoria": "3",
    "DataEntrada": "20120728",
    "DataSaida": "20120730",
    "Marca": null,
    "Endereco": "RUA MARTINHO PRADO, 173",
    "Descricao": "O 155 Hotel trabalha com o conceito de Low Cost de hotel econômico, oferecendo praticidade e comodidade a um baixo custo. Nosso Hotel está instalado no bairro Consolação, num dos melhores pontos do centro da cidade de São Paulo, pois está cercado por ótimas opções gastronômicas e da Avenida Augusta, além de fácil acesso para shoppings, aeroportos, teatros, cinemas, roteiros de compras e a poucos metros do metrô Anhangabaú. Além de oferecer aos seus hóspedes um espaço incomparável em São Paulo, o Hotel 155 busca através de novas tecnologias de inteligência ambiental manter-se como uma instituição sustentável com o reuso das águas da chuva e também sistema economizador de energia. Juntos estes fatores permitem  o 155 a ser um hotel econômico, oferecendo um preço justo aos visitantes da cidade de São Paulo.\r\nOs hóspedes do hotel poderão contar com serviço de Concierge para orientação e apoio e internet central gratuita. Na área de convenções serão duas salas de reuniões para pequenos e médios eventos, além de serviço ágil e prático.\r\n\r\n",
    "Thumbnail": "http://hoteles.internos.hotusa.com/upload/hoteles/web/thum/692547.jpg",
    "Foto": "http://www.hotelresb2b.com/images/hoteles/264280_fotpe1_FACHADA.jpg",
    "Latitude": "-23.550278",
    "Longitude": "-46.645846",
    "Tarifas": [{
        "CodigoQuarto": "SG",
        "Descricao": "Individual",
        "CodigoRefeicao": "BB",
        "Preco": "267.84",
        "Moeda": "DO",
        "Disponibilidade": "OK",
        "Linhas": ["SG#2#VR#133.92#0#BB#OK#20120728#20120729#DO#1-0#0#0#0#", "SG#2#VR#133.92#0#BB#OK#20120729#20120730#DO#1-0#0#0#0#"]
    }, {
        "CodigoQuarto": "DU",
        "Descricao": "Dobleuso (para 1 pers)",
        "CodigoRefeicao": "BB",
        "Preco": "267.84",
        "Moeda": "DO",
        "Disponibilidade": "OK",
        "Linhas": ["DU#2#VR#133.92#0#BB#OK#20120728#20120729#DO#1-0#0#0#0#", "DU#2#VR#133.92#0#BB#OK#20120729#20120730#DO#1-0#0#0#0#"]
    }]
}]
```

I need to walk inside an collection that exists inside the actual item.

How I do this?

Best Regards,

Milton

Comment: post JSON. I don't think what you have posted is a right way to iterate through JSON.

Comment: I have edited my post with jSon Data.

Comment: your JSON is not valid, please correct it.

Comment: this jSon is generated by c# function. whats is  not correct?

Comment: yeahhh, i'm sorry. I will validate now!

Answer (score 1):

asssuming you want to loop through all Tarifas inside of the JSON data. You can use JSON.Parse, assuming the data is a JSON object.

```
    var items = JSON.parse(data);
    if (items != null || !($.isEmptyObject(items))) {

        var firstLevel;
        var i;
        var cnt = items.length;

        for (i = 0; i < cnt; i++) {

            firstLevel = items[i];

            if (firstLevel) {

                var tarifas = firstLevel.Tarifas;
                var x;
                var xcnt = tarifas.length;
                for (x = 0; x < xcnt; x++) {
                    var currentTarifas = tarifas[x];
                    if (currentTarifas) {
                        if (currentTarifas.CodigoQuarto == "SG") {

                            // do some stuff, you can alert all the current tarifas properties if you want
                            alert(currentTarifas.CodigoRefeicao);
                            alert(currentTarifas.Moeda);
                        }

                    }
                }
            }

        }


    }
```

Assuming I understand the jquery way to do it, this should work

```
 $.each(data, function (i, element) {
        var tmp = $('#itemBusca').html();
        $('#buscas').append(_.template(tmp, element));

        $.each(element.Tarifas, function (x, tarifas) {
            alert(tarifas.CodigoQuarto);
        });
    });
```

Comment: exists an way to do it with jQuery?

Comment: I think the jquery I posted should work. I have no way to test it. Let me know.

Comment: when I use this code, the each element.Tarifas does not working perfect, this code block is walking in all Tarifas off items in my jSon

Comment: well it would because its looping through all of them. First you are looping through all of the first level objects. inside of that loop, you are looping through all Tarifas objects inside of the current element. If you are alerting, as I have shown, you would think that its looping through all Tarifas objects at once, but its really not. Are you trying to only look at a certain Tarifas object?

Comment: yeah, I'm lookin for Tarifas inside each first level. I think, when i use this code block over! there is something wrong?

Comment: What are you trying to do with the Tarifas object? what is the purpose of your app?